# Часть речи слова "нерастворимый"

Tags: частица-не, причастия, причастный-оборот

наткнулась на сайте Грамота.ру на данный вопрос. Можете подсказать, по какой причине в данном случае слово нерастворимый является прилагательным? Поскольку я бы выделила "продукт, не растворимый в воде" как причастный оборот и употребила раздельное написание с частицей не.

[image: фото вопроса]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причастие несовершенного вида, настоящего времени от слова растворять это
**растворяемый**.
Если бы такого слова не было, тогда бы **растворимый** могло употребляться и как прилагательное и как причастие. Но в данном случае для причастия есть отдельное слово.

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/растворимый](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/растворяемый](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Answer (score 2):

Есть конкретное правило, говорящее о том, как образуются причастия. О нем написано в учебниках по русскому языку:

> Причастия настоящего времени (и действительные, и страдательные)
> образуются только от глаголов несовершенного вида (у глаголов
> совершенного вида нет причастий настоящего времени)

Слово "растворить", от которого было образовано "растворимый", является переходным глаголом совершенного вида, поэтому от него не может быть образовано причастие с суффиксом "им".

Comment: Хорошее добавление. То есть причастия-прилагательные настоящего времени ("им" суффикс) могут происходить только от глаголов несовершенного вида, коим глагол "растворить" не является. Например, мнимый/гонимый - и причастие и прилагательное.